# Custom UITableViewCells repeats row after scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

**I'm looking for solution...**

*Code:*

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ItemCardapio";
    NSString *nibName = @"ItemCardapioCell";

    ItemCardapioCell *cell = (ItemCardapioCell *) [self.restaurantsList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) { 
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil]; 
        cell = (ItemCardapioCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];

        [cell initCellWithRestaurant:@"" tipoRestaurante:@""];      
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: 1. Looking for solution for what? 2. Add some meaningful comment to your code! 3. Format your code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find that with problems with cell repeating, the problem tends to occur when you put stuff you shouldn't in the `if (cell == nil)` bit.

The reason being is that the table view will end up using an incorrect re-used cell if you don't update certain aspects of your cell appropriately.

Try taking anything which directly changes your cell out of that `if (cell == nil)` bit, and it should stop problems with repeating cells.

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I use for Custom cells:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ItemCardapioCell";

    ItemCardapioCell *cell = (ItemCardapioCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSLog(@"Creating Cell");

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ItemCardapioCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
        {
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[ItemCardapioCell class]])
            {
                cell = (ItemCardapioCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Don't work :( .There is one UIScrollview into the cell that load some subviews. These cells are repeating every 3 rows. Sorry my bad english!

Comment: You have a UIScrollview in a UITableViewCell, every third row? How are implementing(adding) the UIScrollView to the cell?  I don't see anything about that in the question.The code I wrote is just to get a custom cell loaded into the tableview for every row.

Comment: I have a UIScrollView inside ItemCardapioCell that load some subviews. My idea is make horizontal navigation every row, but some rows are repeating.